# Coverity and "Your request for analysis of Phonations/TravisTest failed"

Tags: macos, qt, code-analysis, travis-ci, coverity

I'm trying to add [Coverity Scan static analysis](https://scan.coverity.com) to my Qt Mac project but I'm not able to submit the build using travis.

Here is my coverity specific travis setup:

```
addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: Phonations/TravisTest
      description: Build submitted via Travis CI
    notification_email: martin@phonations.com
    build_command_prepend: cov-configure --comptype clangcxx --compiler clang++ --template
    build_command_prepend: qmake QtTest.pro
    build_command: make -j 4
    branch_pattern: coverity
```

And here is the result I got by mail:

```
Your request for analysis of Phonations/TravisTest  is failed.
Analysis status: Failure
    Please fix the error and upload the build again.

    Error details:
    Build uploaded has not been compiled fully. Please fix any compilation error. You may have to run bin/cov-configure as described in the article on Coverity Community. Last few lines of cov-int/build-log.txt should indicate 85% or more compilation units ready for analysis
    For more detail explanation on the error, please check: https://communities.coverity.com/message/4820

    If your build process isn't going smoothly, email us at scan-admin@coverity.com
    with your cov-int/build-log.txt file attached for assistance, or post your issue
    to the Coverity Community at https://communities.coverity.com/community/scan-(open-source)/content
```

There is not really MacOS specific explanation in the documentation. Anyone has an idea how to submit it?

Comment: I tried to submit it via http://travis-ci.org

Comment: What's your GitHub account ? Please post project you try to compile/upload with TravisCI to Coverity Scan.

Comment: I just triggered a new build and it seems to be working now: https://scan.coverity.com/projects/phonations-travistest (github link: https://github.com/Phonations/travistest)

Comment: In fact it runs ok on my test project (TravisTest) but failed on my main project (https://github.com/Phonations/joker/tree/coverity): https://scan.coverity.com/projects/phonations-joker?tab=overview